# regex that matches only digits,digits with comma and parenthesis but not quotes

Tags: regex, quotes

I am working on this regex which seems to work for most cases except one and i need help in figuring out how to make it to work with below scenarios
 My string is as below and the regex has to match only numbers, numbers with commas, numbers with parenthesis or number with commas and parenthesis. Exception to this rule is it should not match numbers with above scenarios which are in quotes.

```
(  123 122,1232  (123123123) "(123,12321)"    ,1212  12132,121,  "123423"  "1234,12343"  abc,1233  1233,abc)

123 match <br>
122,1232 match<br>
(123123123) match<br>
"123,12321" should not match since it is in quotes<br>
,1212 its fine to match or not match this case<br>
12132,121 match<br>
"123423" should not match again because of quotes<br>
"1234,12343" should not match same reason as above<br>
abc,1233 should not match the numbers here<br>
1234,abc should not match here<br>
```

Regex that I came up with:

```
((?=\s)[\d,]+(?=\)|\s))(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Please help me understand why `abc,1233` matches

Comment: Just wanted to mention that its not a repeated question and I did search for help in SOF to come up with that regex to some extent

Comment: I think I'd be inclined to do it in 2 steps. First remove all the quoted content, then match the remaining numbers. It seems doing it all in a single regex may make it unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Matching and removing all of the quoted content should be easy, assuming the quotes are all closed.

Comment: First of all thank you what are the ideas unfortunately I do not have that option 2 remove those double quotes as I have to offset the strings based on matches

Comment: What editor, OS, RDBMS or whatever are you doing this in?  Not all regex engines are created equal.

Comment: I should have stated this earlier, my apologies. It's in JavaScript

Comment: This is for anyone looking for a solution to above
((?<=\s|\()[\d,]+(?=\)|\s))(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$) regex worked fine for chrome > 62 version  and or > ES2017

Answer (score 0):

The Regex you came with didn't work for me when I tried it, so I came with an alternative solution, hope it helps:

```
(?<=\s)(\(?[0-9,]+\)?)(?=\s)
```

Here you make a lookahead and lookbehind for spaces. Then include the match only if the parenthesis are surrounding it (discard if parenthesis are in the middle of the match) and then match for numbers and comas.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, this regex works for all the scenarios I stated. But unfortunately negative lookahead does not work in javascript